# Edit Servlet that display the selected dropwdown value from database

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, web-applications, drop-down-menu

i want to display the selected dropwdown value so that the admin can edit the form without having to choose the value again. i tried this code but it wont work, the value doesnt show the selected value, it requires the admin to choose again instead..is there any faulty? can any of you suggest some code or repair mine?

```
    pw.println("<div class=\"form-group\">");
    pw.println("<label class=\"control-label col-lg-2\">Employment Type <span class=\"required\">*</span></label>");
    pw.println("<div class=\"col-lg-10\">");
    pw.println("<select class=\"form-control m-bot15\" name=\"j_empType\" value='"+ j.getJobemptype() +"' required/> \n " +
    "<option value=\"\" selected disabled>Please Select...</option> \n " +
    "<option value=\"Permanent\">Permanent</option> \n " +
    "<option value=\"Contract\">Contract</option> \n " +
    "<option value=\"Temporary\">Temporary</option> \n " +
    "<option value=\"Part Time\">Part Time</option>");
    pw.println("</select>");
    pw.println("</div>");
    pw.println("</div>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finally got it hahaha

```
pw.println("<div class=\"form-group\">");
   pw.println("<label class=\"control-label col-lg-2\">Employment Type <span class=\"required\">*</span></label>");
   pw.println("<div class=\"col-lg-10\">");

   if(!"".equalsIgnoreCase(j.getJobemptype()) && j.getJobemptype()!=null){

        if(j.getJobemptype().equalsIgnoreCase("Permanent")){

            pw.println("<select class=\"form-control m-bot15\" name=\"j_empType\" value='"+ j.getJobemptype() +"' required/> \n " +
               "<option value='"+ j.getJobemptype() +"'>"+j.getJobemptype()+"</option>\n " +
               "<option value=\"Contract\">Contract</option> \n " +
               "<option value=\"Temporary\">Temporary</option> \n " +
               "<option value=\"Part Time\">Part Time</option>");
            pw.println("</select>");

        }else if(j.getJobemptype().equalsIgnoreCase("Contract")){

            pw.println("<select class=\"form-control m-bot15\" name=\"j_empType\" value='"+ j.getJobemptype() +"' required/> \n " +
               "<option value='"+ j.getJobemptype() +"'>"+j.getJobemptype()+"</option>\n " +
               "<option value=\"Permanent\">Permanent</option> \n " +
               "<option value=\"Temporary\">Temporary</option> \n " +
               "<option value=\"Part Time\">Part Time</option>");
            pw.println("</select>");
        }else if(j.getJobemptype().equalsIgnoreCase("Temporary")){

            pw.println("<select class=\"form-control m-bot15\" name=\"j_empType\" value='"+ j.getJobemptype() +"' required/> \n " +
               "<option value='"+ j.getJobemptype() +"'>"+j.getJobemptype()+"</option>\n " +
               "<option value=\"Permanent\">Permanent</option> \n " +
               "<option value=\"Contract\">Contract</option> \n " +
               "<option value=\"Part Time\">Part Time</option>");
            pw.println("</select>");

        }else if(j.getJobemptype().equalsIgnoreCase("Part Time")){

                            pw.println("<select class=\"form-control m-bot15\" name=\"j_empType\" value='"+ j.getJobemptype() +"' required/> \n " +
                              "<option value='"+ j.getJobemptype() +"'>"+j.getJobemptype()+"</option>\n " +
                              "<option value=\"Permanent\">Permanent</option> \n " +
                              "<option value=\"Contract\">Contract</option> \n " +
                              "<option value=\"Temporary\">Temporary</option>");
                            pw.println("</select>");

                            }
                              }else {
                                pw.println("<select class=\"form-control m-bot15\" name=\"j_empType\" value='"+ j.getJobemptype() +"' required/> \n " +
                                  "<option value=\"Permanent\">Permanent</option> \n " +
                                  "<option value=\"Contract\">Contract</option> \n " +
                                  "<option value=\"Temporary\">Temporary</option> \n " +
                                  "<option value=\"Part Time\">Part Time</option>");
                                pw.println("</select>");
                                  }
    pw.println("</div>");
    pw.println("</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your code as it is a bit unformatted and useless.
I think you mean something like :

```
for(MyEnum e : MyEnum.values()){
      pw.println("<option value=\""+e.name()+"\">"e.name()"</option>");
}
```

?

Comment: this is how we want to populate the dropdown values with db values right? but what if its the first data? then value wont be available.. :(